# SqlAlchemy - Multiple Columns for func sum

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Currently the query that I am using is as follows:

```
Model.query.with_entities(Model.m_t,
                    func.sum(Model.a),func.sum(Model.b),
                    func.sum(Model.c),func.sum(Model.d),
                    func.sum(Model.f)).group_by(Model.g).\
                    filter(*queries).paginate(page_number, page_size, False
                    )
```

Although this works as expected, but as you can see if the number of columns increase(**for func sum**), the code gets repetitive.
After searching for a while, I came up with this :

```
col_headers = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"]
search_columns = [getattr(Model, i) for i in col_headers]
Model.query.with_entities(Model.m_t,
                         func.sum(*search_columns)).group_by(Model.g).\
                         filter(*queries).paginate(page_number, page_size, False
                         )
```

But this does not work as expected. I get the following errors

> can't adapt type 'InstrumentedAttribute' Exception  as not enough
> values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

I know I'm missing something minor here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you should apply `sum` to each column separately:

`search_columns = [db.func.sum(getattr(Model, i)) for i in col_headers]`

2. you can use [`Query.add_columns`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.add_columns) to add columns to the query results:

`query = query.add_columns(*search_columns)`

or you can pass them directly:

`Model.query.with_entities(Model.m_t, *search_columns)`

---

Putting it all together:

```
col_headers = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"]
search_columns = [db.func.sum(getattr(Model, i)) for i in col_headers]
query = (
    Model.query.with_entities(Model.m_t, *search_columns)
    .group_by(Model.g)
    .filter(*queries)
    .paginate(page_number, page_size, False)
)
```